# What is the efficient way to get the fields from this JSON object?

Tags: json, parsing, gson, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I've the following code that returns json object. And I need to filter sender email, subject, and creationDate. The code does the job but I felt like there is an efficient way to do it. I appreciate your suggestion.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response =
                            restTemplate.exchange(app.getResourceUrl() + personnelEmail+
                            MESSAGE+"/?$select=Sender,Subject,CreatedDateTime", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

                    String str=response.getBody();
                    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray arrayList= (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("value");

                    List l=arrayList.toList();

                    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
                        HashMap<String,HashMap> hashMap=(HashMap<String,HashMap>)l.get(i);

                        HashMap<String,HashMap> sender= hashMap.get("sender");
                        HashMap<String,String> senderEmail= sender.get("emailAddress");

                        String email= senderEmail.get("address");

                    }
```

Here is the json object I receive from MS Office API.

> {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('user34.onmicrosoft.com')/messages(sender,subject,createdDateTime)","value":[{"@odata.etag":"W/\”sljkasfdiou7978klosadf\"","id”:"lkjasdfu97978KLJASDFS_WGHJJ76J897DKdcuvtymBTItq836K34PUAAAvoK3SAAA=","createdDateTime":"2016-08-27T04:07:08Z","subject":"View
>   your Office 365 Enterprise E3 billing
>   statement","sender":{"emailAddress":{"name":"Microsoft Online Services
>   Team","address”:"T45763@email.microsoftonline.com"}}},{"@odata.etag":"W/\”JUU70303\"","id”:”UEYO93988FK;O38GV3J884=","createdDateTime":"2016-08-26T15:28:47Z","subject":"Order
>   confirmation: Thank you for your
>   purchase","sender":{"emailAddress":{"name":"Microsoft Online Services
>   Team","address":"obue733@email.microsoftonline.com"}}},{"@odata.etag":"W/\”LJKOIU987983\"","id”:”ladjksflk83l.x8783LKFW3=","createdDateTime":"2016-06-24T03:03:26Z","subject":"Attention:
>   Your Microsoft Azure Active Directory Premium trial subscription will
>   be disabled soon","sender":{"emailAddress":{"name":"Microsoft Online
>   Services Team","address":"635cdeee@email.microsoftonline.com"}}}]}

Comment: i would recommend you spend some time learning FASTER XML  jackson json parser. especially http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Office 365 REST API response payload also includes common [annotations](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html#_Instance_Annotations) such as:

- `odata.context`: the context URL of the payload
- `odata.etag`: the ETag of the entity, as appropriate

The below picture demonstrates it

[image]

As you've already might guessed it could be controlled via [`odata.metadata` parameter](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html#_Controlling_the_Amount):

> The `odata.metadata parameter` can be applied to the Accept header of
>   an OData request to influence how much control information will be
>   included in the response.

**Example (C# version)**

The example demonstrates how to set `odata.metadata=none` format parameter via `Accept` header to *indicate that the service SHOULD omit control information*

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
     var url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$select=Sender,Subject,DateTimeCreated";
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse(GetMediaType("none",false,false)));
     var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
     var data = JObject.Parse(result);

     foreach (var item in data["value"])
     {
        //process item;
     }
}
```

where

```
private static string GetMediaType(string metadata,bool streaming,bool IEEE754Compatible)
{
   return String.Format("application/json; OData.metadata={0}; OData.streaming={1}; IEEE754Compatible={2}",metadata,streaming, IEEE754Compatible);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example on how to omit the unnecessary data. At least it helped me to avoid the Odata related responses that we dont need but I still have to go through the same route as I followed on my code to retrieve subject. I thought there would be a way like jsonObject.get("value.sender") but it didnt work that way.